# Fork "free" sshd?

Tags: authentication, posix, fork, sshd

Is there a way to run `sshd` such that it can (at least for a limited number of log-ins) successfully return a prompt (likely busybox) even while fork is unavailable (e.g. out of PIDs)?

It seems to me this should be possible by, for example, the sshd pre-forking and keeping a pool of `getty`s to use to service log in requests.

Comment: Actually, I don't know... But can you tell us why you want to do this? This may provide some hints eventual answers... : )

Comment: @Macmade It's quite legitimate. Suppose the box is overloaded and you want to SSH to it but you can't because `fork` fails.

Comment: @Macmade: cnicutar got it in one.

Answer (score 3):

SSHD can be launched with the `-D` or `-d` option.

**-D:**

> When this option is specified, sshd will not detach and does not become a daemon.
>   This allows easy monitoring of sshd.

**-d:**

> Debug mode.
>   The server sends verbose debug output to standard error, and does not put itself in the background.
>   The server also will not fork and will only process one connection.  This option is only intended for debugging for the server.
> Multiple -d options increase the debugging level. Maximum is 3.

I guess your best choice is to run a separate `SSHD` process, listening on another port, with the `-d` option.

So when the «normal» SSHD fails, you will still be able to switch to the other one, using the alternate port.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but gets some of the same end effects.